Changing scalars of a tensor product $N \otimes_B \ A$
So I was working on exercise 1.5.E. in Vakil (which is to show that restriction of scalars is right adjoint to the tensor product), but I got caught on understanding how to think of a tensor product after restricting scalars (after which it won't even be a tensor product?).
More explicitely, assume that we have a morphism of rings $f:B \to A$, an $A$-module $M$ and a $B$-module $N$. The task was to show that there is an adjunction
$$ Hom_A(N \otimes_B A, M) \cong Hom_B(N, M_B), $$
where $M_B$ denotes the restriction of scalars. I first defined the mapping $Hom_A(N \otimes_B A, M) \to Hom_B(N, M_B)$ by for each $g \in Hom_A(N \otimes_B A, M)$ defining $h \in Hom_B(N, M_B)$ by
$$ h(n)=g(n\otimes 1), $$
by thinking of the RHS as an element of $M_B$. However, when showing linearity of this function I feel intuitively that the following should hold, but I can't put my finger on why:
$$ h(bn) = g((bn) \otimes 1) = g((n \otimes f(b))) = g(f(b)(n \otimes 1)) = f(b)g(n\otimes 1) = bh(n). $$
Basically, I struggle to justify the second and third equalities; my thinking if the following, but I'm not quite sure if it's sound:
Thinking about $(bn) \otimes 1$ as an element of the $B$-module $N \otimes_B A$ (which is a tensor product in the categories of $B$-modules), we get
$$ (bn) \otimes 1 = (n \otimes f(b)).$$
If these two elements are equal in the $B$-module, they should also be equal in the $A$-module, and so we get in the $A$-module
$$ (bn) \otimes 1 = n \otimes f(b) = f(b)(n \otimes 1). $$
Is this thinking correct? I don't feel very confident about it, but it also feels right...
Thanks in advance!

You are right! This set has both a B-module structure and an A-module structure, and multiplication with A and B commutes.
